# UWP IScrollSnapPointsInfo

Tags: windows, uwp, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

[image]I want to create a custom panel with the implementation of IScrollSnapPointsInfo, i'm setting the snapoffset to 500px, i want to listen for an event for every 500px change, currently i'm listening to "HorizontalSnapPointsChanged" event, but not sure how to invoke it on every 500px change. Please help me.

Comment: Please show me your code how you define your custom panel and implement the IScrollSnapPointsInfo interface. And what's your final requirement?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT My Requirement is a calender implementation like the image mentioned above. I have a panel with width say 1*10^6, in the i have 21 Grid(A single day), i need to arrange the 21 days in the panel, when i scroll left 1st grid should be moved to last viceversa, so that it gives a infinte scroll effect. And whild scrolling i need to snap the view,, for eg if a single day width is 500px then a single scroll should move the entire day. Hope this explains clearly, please suggest me ideas on this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a panel with width say 1*10^6, in the i have 21 Grid(A single day), i need to arrange the 21 days in the panel, when i scroll left 1st grid should be moved to last viceversa, so that it gives a infinte scroll effect. And whild scrolling i need to snap the view,, for eg if a single day width is 500px then a single scroll should move the entire day. Hope this explains clearly, please suggest me ideas on this.

Using the IScrollSnapPointsInfo is the way to go for custom panels. The implementation gets used when the panel is placed in a ScrollViewer directly (scrollViewer.Content == panel) or when it’s the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl.

I've made a code sample for your. This should be a good starting point for you.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Center" HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <local:CustomPanel HorizontalSnapPointsChanged="CustomPanel_HorizontalSnapPointsChanged">
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                <TextBlock Text="1" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="2" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="3" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="4" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="5" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="6" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="7" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="8" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="9" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="10" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="11" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="12" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="13" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="14" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="15" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="16" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="17" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="18" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="19" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="20" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
            <Grid  Height="200" Width="500" Background="Black" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1 1 1 1">
                        <TextBlock Text="21" FontSize="100" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
        </local:CustomPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

```cs
public class CustomPanel:Panel, IScrollSnapPointsInfo
{
    private float horizontalRegularSnapPointsInterval;
    private float verticalRegularSnapPointsInterval;



    public CustomPanel()
    {
        horizontalRegularSnapPointsInterval = 500f;
        verticalRegularSnapPointsInterval = 35f;
    }

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, child.DesiredSize.Width, child.DesiredSize.Height));
            x = x + child.DesiredSize.Width;

        }
        x = 0;
        return finalSize;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        Size size = new Size(0, 0);

        foreach (UIElement child in Children)
        {
            child.Measure(availableSize);

        }

        size.Width = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Width) ?
           500*21 : availableSize.Width;

        size.Height = double.IsPositiveInfinity(availableSize.Height) ?
           200 : availableSize.Height;

        return size;
    }



    public IReadOnlyList<float> GetIrregularSnapPoints(Orientation orientation, SnapPointsAlignment alignment)
    {
        // Returning null because the exposed snap points are regular instead of irregular. 
        return null;
    }

    public float GetRegularSnapPoints(Orientation orientation, SnapPointsAlignment alignment, out float offset)
    {
        offset = 0f;

        if (orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            switch (alignment)
            {
                case SnapPointsAlignment.Near:
                    offset = (float)Margin.Left;
                    break;
                case SnapPointsAlignment.Center:
                    offset = horizontalRegularSnapPointsInterval / 2f + (float)Margin.Left;
                    break;
                case SnapPointsAlignment.Far:
                    offset = (float)Margin.Right;
                    break;
            }
            return horizontalRegularSnapPointsInterval;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (alignment)
            {
                case SnapPointsAlignment.Near:
                    offset = (float)Margin.Top;
                    break;
                case SnapPointsAlignment.Center:
                    offset = verticalRegularSnapPointsInterval / 2f + (float)Margin.Top;
                    break;
                case SnapPointsAlignment.Far:
                    offset = (float)Margin.Bottom;
                    break;
            }
            return verticalRegularSnapPointsInterval;
        }
    }

    public bool AreHorizontalSnapPointsRegular
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool AreVerticalSnapPointsRegular
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<object> HorizontalSnapPointsChanged;
    public event EventHandler<object> VerticalSnapPointsChanged;

    // Invoke when the regular interval for the horizontal snap points changes
    private void UpdateHorizontalRegularSnapPointsInterval(float interval)
    {
        if (interval != horizontalRegularSnapPointsInterval)
        {
            horizontalRegularSnapPointsInterval = interval;
            RaiseHorizontalSnapPointsChanged();
        }
    }

    // Invoke when the regular interval for the vertical snap points changes
    private void UpdateVerticalRegularSnapPointsInterval(float interval)
    {
        if (interval != verticalRegularSnapPointsInterval)
        {
            verticalRegularSnapPointsInterval = interval;
            RaiseVerticalSnapPointsChanged();
        }
    }

    private void RaiseHorizontalSnapPointsChanged()
    {
        HorizontalSnapPointsChanged?.Invoke(this, null);
    }

    private void RaiseVerticalSnapPointsChanged()
    {
        VerticalSnapPointsChanged?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @xavier will try it and let u know.

Comment: i tried the code sample "CustomPanel_HorizontalSnapPointsChanged" is not being called. Any ideas? And how t0 handle the item removal from first and adding to last vice versa.